# Let $f$ be a function ​satisfying such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f$ be a function ​satisfying such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(x)=x^2g(x)$ for all $x$ and $y$, $g(x)$ is continuous function.then find $f''(x)$.

As we can see that $f(ax)=af(x)$, so can we take $f(x)=ax$? But if do so, then there is no use of $g(x)$. What am I missing here?

Comment: $g$ really is somewhat of a distraction, the important part is the continuity of $g$, which gives continuity of $f$. And then it also allows you to determine $a$...

Comment: Actually, $g$ makes the argument a little easier. As a hint, try to use the functional equation for $x=y \ne 0$, and see what you get for $g$.

Comment: OP, how do you prove that $f(ax)=af(x)$ for $a=\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @vadim123 My bad. I didn't consider that while doing calculation. Thanx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We immediately get $f(0)=0$, $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and by induction $f(nx)=nf(x)$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. In fact, as $f$ is odd, $f(nx)=nf(x)$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ and hence $qf(\frac pqx)=f(px)=pf(x)$ for $p,q\in \Bbb Z$, $q\ne 0$, i.e., $f(cx)=cf(x)$ at least for $c\in\Bbb Q$. In particular, $f(x)=xf(1)$ for $x\in\Bbb Q$. As $g$ is continuous, so is $f$, an we conclude that $f(x)=xf(1)$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$. This already shows that $f'(x)=f(1)$ is constant, hence $f''(x)=0$.

But in fact we already have $f(x)=0$ for otherwise there is no continuous $g$ with $cx=x^2g(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Can we say that $f(x)=kx+C$, where $k=f'(0)$ and $C$ is constant? I found it by finding partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ and then got $f'(x)=f'(y)$ and then put y=0 and hence solved differential equation.

Comment: @Ananya, But it doesn't satisfy the equation, instead you can use an other way by a change of variable as $(x,y)$ to $(-x,x+h)$ where and then use the limit as $h \to 0$

Comment: @Mann It will satisfy the equation as $f(0)=0$, hence $C=0$. So ultimately $f(x)=kx$

Comment: $C=0$ is exactly what i wanted to say, but i noticed that after i had commented.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already proved that $f(ax)=af(x)$ for all $x$, then the fact that $f(x+y)=f(x)+g(x)$ tells you that $f(x)$ is linear. All linear functions have constant first derivative (as you can check from the definition of derivative), and hence vanishing second derivatives, i.e. $f''(x)=0$ for all $x$.